# What happened to my edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

A few minutes ago I made an edit to a question ([How to tell boss that we need a test plan and to ensure developers use the QA process?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/139151/how-to-tell-boss-that-we-need-a-test-plan-and-to-ensure-developers-use-the-qa-pr)), by correcting a lot of its grammar, improving the formatting, Highlighting the actual question, etc..

After saving my edit it was marked as "waiting for peer review"; yet a minute later, my edit was gone without a trace and someone else's edit (with far less changes) is now the last edit to the question.

I added the **Bug** tag to *this* question because I didn't expect to "lose" an edit without a trace.

**Is my edit still under review or as it been rejected? Where can I see a list of my edits and their current state? Should I have received a notification about the rejection, if that is what happened to my edit?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This is not a bug, your edit was rejected by [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)

This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit. When you have less than 2000 rep points, you can only suggest edits. Those edits are then reviewed by more trusted users (more than 2000 rep points).
However, when a trusted users do an edit, it is automatically and instantaneously accepted, replacing your current edit.
This is what happened here. You and [jay](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/5652/jay) have done an edit at the same time. You suggested the edit, and a few moments later, jay submitted his edit, overriding yours.

### How to see your edits

You can see it in your [profile](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/104547/niko1978?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), all actions tabs, under "suggestion" subtab.

[image: rejected]

You can also follow the link, and access to the edit to see who accept/reject it

[image: edit]

Comment: The edit was rejected by the system as a result of unfortunate timing.  No human rejected your edit, so if your suggestions still apply, please try again.

Comment: Thank you both! Someone else made a similar edit in the meantime, so I think that my suggestion doesn't apply any longer. But again, thank you both for clearing this up for me. :-)